# Find out the encrypted number or letter

Tags: visual, steganography

#### This image:

[image: dots]

Has en encrypted letter or number in it.

I am asking you to not only find out what the number or letter is,
but am also asking you, to find it out, using the proper method.

(I'm curious to see how ingenuous the people are here at puzzling)

Good Luck!

#### Post Script:

This is my first at puzzling. Hope I didn't miss anything!

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This seems pretty interesting - it looks like an overhead view of buildings at first glance, but it seems too random for that. I'm gonna have to mull this one over for a while.

Comment: It's very easy to read, you just have to know how to.

Comment: I guess I could have noted that you need at least two eyes to see it properly

Comment: @ProBlaster I have to say, the image is too long for me to see even with two eyes. I know the method. I just can't "bend" that far.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck If you can't "bend" that far, than just stand farther away from your screen. (less "eye crossing strain")

Comment: @ProBlaster yeah, I found the zoom feature of my browser quite useful. I don't see it, but I was able to cross. I've never done these so I probably just don't have the eyes for such detail.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck It takes a little while to get used to crosseye3d

Comment: @ProBlaster I figured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's...

> the number seven, hidden as a Magic Eye picture (stereogram). I can't view them myself, so here's a modified version that overlaps the two images.
>   [image]

Comment: 12 minutes, that's all my question lasted, wow you guys are smart. Great Job.